# SQL - Getting day for the whole week

Tags: t-sql

I want to get the whole day of the week depend on the date, my query is working and getting the result that I want but when the date value is Sunday, result changes.
I'm starting the result from Mon to Sunday.
Examples below:

My Code:

```
 SELECT UserID,Scdl_TkIN as TimeIn, Scdl_TkOut as  [TimeOut] 
   FROM EmployeeTimekeeping 
   WHERE CONVERT(DATE,Scdl_TkIN) >= dateadd(day, 2-datepart(dw, '2022-04-23'),CONVERT(date,'2022-04-23')) 
    AND CONVERT(DATE,Scdl_TkIN) <  dateadd(day, 9-datepart(dw, '2022-04-23'), CONVERT(date,'2022-04-23'))AND UserID ='15020009'
    ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE,Scdl_TkIN)
```

[image]

1st display is correct, but when I change the value into '2022-04-24' , the result is now the second pic but I want the result still 1st pic.

Comment: Judging from your table name `TimeKeeping` you will need to deal with dates, weekdays, weekends, holiday etc. It is to your advantage to setup a calendar table. It makes your query very easy. (including this)

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right you want the whole week of data given a single date.

I'm not 100% sure about your date logic and I'd rather use the WEEK as a filter as it seems clearer, that said the issue you have is the value of `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`.
By default its value is 7, meaning that Sunday is considered the first day of the week, that's why you get that "unexpected" result.

here is my solution, but just setting `SET DATEFIRST 1;` should give you the expected result.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
SELECT
   UserID
  ,Scdl_TkIN as TimeIn
  ,Scdl_TkOut as TimeOut
FROM EmployeeTimekeeping 
WHERE
  DATEPART(WEEK,Scdl_TkIN) = DATEPART(WEEK,'2022-04-23')
  AND YEAR(Scdl_TkIN) = YEAR('2022-04-23')
  AND UserID ='15020009'
ORDER BY
  Scdl_TkIN
```

*Note: if you decide to use WEEK for filtering you will have to choose between WEEK and ISO_WEEK*
Edit: when using week you must also consider the year in the filter

Comment: Filtering on `week` is an interesting idea, at least until there is data from more than one year in the table. Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about it, but is simple enough to also put the year in the filter, or to use the dates as you stated